# IE, Jquery, and formy goodness not working

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, forms

After much searching and tweaking, I cannot for the LIFE of me figure out what is wrong.

Problem: IE does not seem to adhere to my functions set in

```
$(document).ready($(function() { ...
```

In FireFox and Chrome the following works:

```
<form id='submit_new_date'>
<input id='new_date' type='text' />
<input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>

$("#submit_new_date").live('submit', function (event) {

    var date = $("#new_date").val();
    var employee = $("#employee_id").val();
    var boxcar = $("#boxcar_id").val();
    if (isDate(date)==false) {
        return false;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                url: 'view/create_new_grouping.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:   'boxcar=' + boxcar + '&employee=' + employee + '&date=' + date,
                success: function(response){
                    $('#content').html(response);
                }
            }); 
    return false;    
    });
```

In IE, this does not work.  It just does the default post action.  Which is why I have both return false and preventDefault in there.  Any insight would be appreciated.

So I don't think it is an asych problem with ajax, because it doesn't seem to run the block of code at all.  Even putting an alert doesn't change any behavior.  Also, the Javascript and html are in separate files obviously.

Comment: Are you capturing a click event that is related to that form and do you prevent its bubbling? That could prevent the submit event from being triggered. Other than that, it's not strictly necessary to use a live event for this kind of work. Since you are registering the handlers in the document ready handler. Live events are relatively new, so they might be buggy. Other than that, you could try switching to a newer jQuery version and see if that resolves the bug. (1.5.2 just out)

Comment: It could be the case that the implementation is not necessary.  I am self taught and might not be aware of the best practices.  However, what I am trying to accomplish is I have several hidden input fields in the PHP script.  If something doesn't go well then I want a certain input from the user.  The entire reason I am using a form is because I want the option of typing something into the input field and hitting enter rather than always resorting to the button.  All the while capturing other inputs from the page and posting to a new PHP view.

Comment: That's totally legit and there is nothing wrong with the concept. Try using `$("#submit_new_date").submit(function (event) { ... });` instead of the `live`-thing. It should work equally well (or hopefully better) in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using using jQuery < 1.4.3 it appears it was a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6359) in IE if `.live('submit')` was called after a `.live('click')`

If upgrading is not an option you could try binding directly to the submit button instead.

```
$("#submit_new_date input[type='submit']").live("click", function(){
 //stuff
});
```

**A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/HdHU5/) example.**

Based upon your comment, if the form is not dynamic (elements are in the dom and not loaded after dom ready) you don't need `.live()`

```
$("#submit_new_date").submit( function (event) {
//do stuff
});
```

**Another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/HdHU5/1/).**

Comment: Avoid binding to buttons as in some cases the button will not be activated when the form is submitted with the Enter key. Personally I would just use normal `bind` instead of `live` on the form submission: it's more likely to be reliable because it doesn't require jQuery to tie itself in knots trying to work around the lack of bubbling for submit events in IE.

Comment: Since you want this code to execute anytime the form is submitted it is perfectly valid use.